# Do in-app purchasing providers like Zong, Paypal, and Boku violate iPhone and Android terms and conditions?

Tags: iphone, android, paypal, itunes, in-app-purchase

I know there are questions posted elsewhere about how to implement in-app purchases on iPhone and Android, but none answer the legality of the solutions today.  At the time of release, there was some dispute over whether some of these solutions violate terms of service, but it's now several months later.  There are also now several exceptions like Amazon, which seem to circumvent iTunes for purchases.

Anyone have a definitive answer?

Comment: Too bad I can't award points for the user name :D

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. Please use qualified legal counsel for legal questions.

Comment: Sorry, @CommonsWare.  I meant to ask what are people using for non-iTunes in-app purchasing.  There has been a lot of discussion in past months, and I'm curious if circumstances have changed.  I understand this isn't legal counsel.  Just want to see what other developers have determined and used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the App Store has two main rules when it comes to in-app purchases (IAP):

1. Buying physical goods or services outside the app using the in-app purchase API is not allowed
2. Using something other than the in-app purchase API to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app is not allowed

Amazon is Ok on both these, but I don't know enough about the Zong, Paypal or Boku apps.